# Bash script keep 'x' amount of characters in directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory

I want to rename a bunch of folders so that they only keep the first 2 letters.

**Example directory:**

```
01_HistoryMuseum
02_McWilliamsHouse
03_VillageLibrary
```

I want to turn that into this:

```
01
02
03
```

Comment: Richard Liu please provide details of what you tried and what didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need a little more info, but assuming you are in directory X and it contains the directories you want to rename, then something like:

```
for D in *
do
   if [ -d ${D} ]
   then
      D2=$( echo ${D} | cut -c1-2 )
      echo "Renaming ${D} to ${D2}"
      mv ${D} ${D2}
   fi
done
```